# Trying to pass an argument to a method and using an if - else if statement to try and direct user to specific method

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to pass an argument to a method, but since the 
showKilometer(int num){ method already has an argument passing through, if-else if statement doesn't work, I've been trying to change showKilometer();  to showKilometer(int num); under the if-else if statement but that doesn't seem to work either

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class a6main {

public static void main(String[] args){

    double distanceMeter;  
    double distanceKilom;
    double distanceInches;
    double distanceFeet;

    System.out.println("Enter a distance in meters:");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    distanceMeter = keyboard.nextDouble();

    while (distanceMeter <= 0){  
    System.out.println("Unable to atain distance less than 0,\n" 
            + "please enter a number grater than 0:\n");
    distanceMeter = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
   showKilometer(distanceMeter);
   menu();
  }

public static void menu(){
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);   
System.out.println("Enter your choice\n"
        + "1. Convert to kilometers\n"
        + "2. Convert to inches\n"
        + "3. Conveert to feet\n"
        + "4. Quit the program");
   int choice = keyboard.nextInt();
    while (choice <= 0 || choice >= 5){
System.out.println("Option unavailble, pleace select a choice from 1 - 4:\n"
        + "1. Convert to kilometers\n"
        + "2. Convert to inches\n"
        + "3. Conveert to feet\n"
        + "4. Quit the program");
   choice = keyboard.nextInt();
   }
if(choice == 1)
   showKilometer();      
else if(choice == 2)
   showInches();
else if(choice == 3)   
   showFeet();
else
    System.out.println("Program terminated.");
    }

    public static void showKilometer(int num){
    System.out.println(num);
    }
    }
```

Comment: I cant see the problem can you tell what happens if you call showKilometer like that: showKilometer(1)

Comment: @user7790438 it prints out the 1 in (1) as 1.0 since it is declared as a double

Comment: And what you need rather that

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: well, I would need for it to switch methods, for example in this case, if the user were to pick choice 1, then it would call the showKilometer(int num) method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should look like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A6Main {

public static void main(String[] args){

    double distanceMeter;  
    double distanceKilom;
    double distanceInches;
    double distanceFeet;

    System.out.println("Enter a distance in meters:");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    distanceMeter = keyboard.nextDouble();

    while (distanceMeter <= 0){  
        System.out.println("Unable to atain distance less than 0,\n" 
                + "please enter a number grater than 0:\n");
        distanceMeter = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    // showKilometer(distanceMeter);
    menu(distanceMeter);
  }

    public static void menu(double distance){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);   
        System.out.println("Enter your choice\n"
                + "1. Convert to kilometers\n"
                + "2. Convert to inches\n"
                + "3. Conveert to feet\n"
                + "4. Quit the program");
        int choice = keyboard.nextInt();
            while (choice <= 0 || choice >= 5){
        System.out.println("Option unavailble, pleace select a choice from 1 - 4:\n"
                + "1. Convert to kilometers\n"
                + "2. Convert to inches\n"
                + "3. Conveert to feet\n"
                + "4. Quit the program");
        choice = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        if(choice == 1)
        showKilometer(distance);      
        else if(choice == 2)
        showInches(distance);
        else if(choice == 3)   
        showFeet(distance);
        else
        System.out.println("Program terminated.");
    }

    public static void showKilometer(double num){
        System.out.println(num);
    }
    public static void showInches(double num){
        System.out.println(num);
    }
    public static void showFeet(double num){
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

You will see I've added the additional methods to do the conversion and I pass the distance into the menu.  Then I use that distance to pass to the conversion method that can do the calculations.

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you just define a new method with no arguments.

```
public static void showKilometer(){
    System.out.println("#### no args ####");
}
```